# Laravel : codition to insert tarificationtache (Syntax error or access violation)

Tags: php, laravel

I have to insert to 'technicien'='technician'  there  'tache'='task'  and 'tarification' ='price'

```
Schema::create('tarificationtaches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->float('tarif', 8,2);
        $table->integer('tache_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tache_id')->references('id')->on('taches');
        $table->integer('technicien_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')- 
        >on('techniciens');
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

each techncien have  to make there  'tache'  then I would like to add a condition in my function to check the insertion if the 'tache' already exists if yes it displays to me existing' tache' if it does not insert in the database

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

    $tarification = new tarificationtache();
    $tarification ->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
    $tarification ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tarification->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $tarification->save();

    return redirect('technicien');  
   }
```

**I have tried this function but i have some error**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $tarification = new tarificationtache();
    $tarification ->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
    $tarification ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tarification->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $tarification = DB::select("select * FROM tarificationtaches where 
     technicien_id = 'technicien_id' and tache_id = input('tache_id')");
        if(request($tarification) > 1)
         echo "Ce technicien a cette tarification";
        else{

        $tarification->save();

 }}
```

**errors**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION 
 projet2.input 
    does not exist (SQL: select * FROM tarificationtaches where \n
     technicien_id = 'technicien_id' and tache_id = input('tache_id'))
```

[form to inset tache and tarif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APyAA.png)

Comment: mysql doesn't have any input function `input('tache_id')` your sql is incorrect

Comment: how can i solved my sql

Comment: What is your end goal exactly? What's the result - I don't really understand your question that well.

Comment: You already have set `$tarification ->tache_id` to the value of `$request->input('tache_id')`, so use `$tarification ->tache_id` in your query.

Comment: I add the interface I have several technician each one must have one or more task and each task to a tarife as indicates the base
i have to add task for each technician but i want to remove the doublet with a condition that check if spot and available with technician x or nn

Comment: @kerbholz  can you explane more please

Comment: As @madalinivascu said there is no input function `input('tache_id')` in SQL. So you need to replace `input('tache_id')` in your query, preferably with `$tarification ->tache_id`, since it already holds the correct value. You might want to get yourself acquainted with basic SQL queries and maybe debugging too. Looking at your query ... `where technicien_id = 'technicien_id'` will yield no results, since there probably is no entry where `technicien_id` is equal to the string `'technicien_id'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can understand, maybe you need something like this?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $count = tarificationtache::where('technicien_id', $request->input('technicien_id'))
        ->where('tache_id', $request->input('tache_id'))
        ->count();
    if ($count > 0) {
        // TODO: adjust response according to your need
        return response()->json(['error' => "Ce technicien a cette tarification"], 400);
    } else {
        $tarification = new tarificationtache;    
        $tarification->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
        $tarification->Tarif = $request->input('Tarif');
        $tarification>technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
        $tarification->save();
        // TODO: adjust response according to your need
        return response()->json($tarification);
    }
}
```

You can check [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) for further details regarding `count` or any other query builder methods in Laravel.

Comment: thak you for answer but it insert in database when i have the same task and it shown me like this            {"tache_id":"3","Tarif":"253","technicien_id":"1","updated_at":"2018-08-17 09:29:27","created_at":"2018-08-17 09:29:27","id":11}

Comment: Ups, my bad. It should be `$count > 0`. I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you very much and if i like shown the message on popop on the same interface how can i do

Comment: There are several ways to do that. The most common one is to submit the form using ajax and show the popup after you got server response (eg. on `done()` in jquery `ajax`). This article can be a good start https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery